# Массив и возращаемое значения в Java

Tags: java, массивы

Есть метод которые обробатывают данные кладет их в несколька массивов и возращает двухмерный массив. Проблема такая что нужно возратить два массива типа String[] и один типа int[]. Как известно их в один массив не вместишь. 
Как можно решить проблмему чтобы я получил примерно такой возвращаемый массив:

```
{ String[] , String[] , int[] };
```

ну и метод примерно такой:

```
    public static void getData(){
      String[] data1 = // получить данные
      String[] data2 = // получить данные
      int[] integetData = // получить данные

      // обрабатоваю


      return new String[]{ data1 , data2};

      // надо как то втолкать массив в return
    }
```

Может по опыту знаете какие нибудь финты

Comment: Можно создать класс, у которого будет три поля -- массивы, и возвращать объект этого класса.

Comment: @post_zeew реально. Я не додумался. Спс за ответ